# standard libraries modules not found in robot framework on centos 7

Tags: python, linux, robotframework, centos7

i am using Robot Framework 5.0.1.dev1 (Python 3.6.8 on linux(centos 7 ,,redhat ) on an vartuial machine

i am facing the same issue same as standard libraries modules not found in robot framework on centos 7

when i right a sample robot script there using built-in library

```
*** Settings ***
Library                             OperatingSystem
Library                             selenium
Library                 BiultIn
Library                             Browser
Documentation     A test suite with a single test for valid login.
...
...               This test has a workflow that is created using keywords in
...               the imported resource file.
Resource          login.resource
*** KeyWords ***
$(result)
*** Test Cases ***
ValidLogin
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Input Username    demo
    Input Password    mode
    Submit Credentials
    Welcome Page Should Be Open
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
MyFirstRobotTest
    Log To Console            Hello Robot World!
    Log To Console            hi
    Log To Console      2+2=
MySecondRobotTest
    Create File                     new_file.txt
   
    Remove File                     new_file.txt
MyNumber
    Should Be Equal $(hi)   $(hi)   Custom error    value=True
```

```
output to is
[ WARN ] Imported library 'selenium' contains no keywords.
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/ashish/first.robot' on line 4: Importing library 'BiultIn' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BiultIn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/lib64/python36.zip
  /usr/lib64/python3.6
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload
  /home/ashish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/ashish/first.robot' on line 5: Importing library 'Browser' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Browser'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/lib64/python36.zip
  /usr/lib64/python3.6
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload
  /home/ashish/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/ashish/first.robot' on line 10: Resource file 'login.resource' does not exist.
==============================================================================
First :: A test suite with a single test for valid login.                     
==============================================================================
ValidLogin                                                            | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Open Browser To Login Page' found.

Also teardown failed:
No keyword with name 'Close Browser' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyFirstRobotTest                                                      Hello Robot World!
.hi
.2+2=
MyFirstRobotTest                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MySecondRobotTest                                                     | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyNumber                                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
First :: A test suite with a single test for valid login.             | FAIL |
4 tests, 3 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/ashish/output.xml
Log:     /home/ashish/log.html
Report:  /home/ashish/report.html


if try to install them

it shows like this

[ashish@localhost ~]$ pip install --upgrade robotframework-builtIn
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-builtIn (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for robotframework-builtIn


pip list :-------------- is as follows
[ashish@localhost ~]$ pip list
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ----------
Appium-Python-Client           1.3.0
bcrypt                         3.2.0
cffi                           1.15.0
cryptography                   36.0.2
decorator                      5.1.1
distlib                        0.3.4
docutils                       0.18.1
dotdict                        0.1
filelock                       3.4.1
importlib-metadata             4.8.3
importlib-resources            5.4.0
kitchen                        1.2.6
numpy                          1.19.5
paramiko                       2.10.3
pbr                            5.8.1
Pillow                         8.4.0
pip                            21.3.1
platformdirs                   2.4.0
psutil                         5.9.0
pycparser                      2.21
Pygments                       2.11.2
PyNaCl                         1.5.0
Pypubsub                       4.0.3
robotframework                 5.0.1.dev1
robotframework-appiumlibrary   1.6.3
robotframework-lint            1.1
robotframework-pythonlibcore   3.0.0
robotframework-ride            2.0b2.dev5
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 5.1.3
robotframework-sshlibrary      3.8.0
scp                            0.14.4
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     39.2.0
six                            1.16.0
stevedore                      3.5.0
typing_extensions              4.1.1
urllib3                        1.26.9
virtualenv                     20.14.0
virtualenv-clone               0.5.7
virtualenvwrapper              4.8.4
wheel                          0.31.1
wxPython                       4.0.7
zipp                           3.6.0
```

what would the issue i am unble to figure it out...... can u help????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors, in your file:

- > [ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/ashish/first.robot' on line 4: Importing library 'BiultIn' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BiultIn'
- This means that library `BiultIn` does not exist. If you wanted to use the builtin library `BuiltIn` you do not need to import.
- `selenium`is not the importable library, it should be `SeleniumLibrary`, and installed with `pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary`.
- `Browser`should have been also installed, and it is not recommended to mix SeleniumLibrary with Browser.

Comment: thank you ..,is it same for process library too

Comment: Good. You should mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

seleniumis not the importable library, it should be SeleniumLibrary, and installed with pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary.